# Linq to Entities: can't get collection query to work

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities, entitycollection

I'm struggling to get a collection of records using L2E. Here's the model view:
http://pascalc.nougen.com/stuffs/aspnet_linq_model2.png

I have a user identifier, which is associated to 1 or many UserGroup which themselves are linked to TestCase. I would like to get all TestCases of all groups the user id X is associated to.

I also notice that I don't get all Project for users that are associated to 2 (or more).

Here's how I do so far:

```
    QASModel.QASEntities qasEntities = new QASModel.QASEntities();
QASModel.User authenticatedUserEntity = (from u in qasEntities.Users
                                         where u.ID.Equals(authenticatedUserId)
                                         select u).FirstOrDefault();
// Get the authenticated user usergroups
var usergroup = authenticatedUserEntity.UserGroups.FirstOrDefault();
// Get all testcases of all user group the authenticated user is associated to
var allTestcases = usergroup.TestCases;
// Get the authenticated user projects based on it's usergroup(s)
var authenticatedUserProjects = usergroup.Projects;
```

authenticatedUserProjects give back only 1 project, where the user is linked to 2 projects.
And allTestcases gives back no result, although there are about 8 entries in TestCases associated to a project associated to one of the same UserGroup the user belongs to.

Thanks

Comment: The trick was to cast the definition as a list: `List<QASModel.TestCase> allTestCases = new EntityCollection<QASModel.TestCase>().ToList();` then concat: `allTestCases = allTestCases.Concat(usergroup.TestCases).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
var usergroup = authenticatedUserEntity.UserGroups.FirstOrDefault();
```

Shouldn't your code get all `UserGroups` of that `User`? The above line will return only 1 `UserGroup`, this is, if the user belongs to more than 1 `UserGroup` the 2nd one won't be returned.

To correct this:

```
var userTestCases = new List<TestCase>();
var userProjects =  new List<Project>();

foreach(UserGroup ug in authenticatedUserEntity.UserGroups)
{
    userTestCases = userTestCases.Concat(ug.TestCases);

    // Get the authenticated user projects based on it's usergroup(s)
    userProjects = userProjects.Concat(ug.Projects);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leniel, the only issue I have now is that when a user has more than 1 usergroup associated, the variables (allTestcases and authenticatedUserProjects) get 'reset' each pass in the foreach(). How can I 'contact' each result in each pass?

Comment: It complains it cannot convert from IEnumerable to List on the concat(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var usergroup = authenticatedUserEntity.UserGroups.FirstOrDefault();
```

probably is wrong, since you want all usergroups the user is associated with. 
In any case you can easily revert the query to work like this

```
var testcases = from tc in new QASModel.QASEntities().TestCases
where tc.UserGroup.UserId == USERID
select tc
```

This way you won't have to execute multiple queries to get all test cases, each FirstOrDefault or ToList or ForEach will actually execute the query.

Comment: Thanks AD.Net but I don't have the property "UserId" in "tc.UserGroup.UserId"
I tried `where tc.UserGroup.Users.Select(x => x.ID.Equals(authenticatedUserId))` but that not good. I'm new to L2E. Thanks

Comment: Well, of course I don't have the context right now with me, so I might have missed it. From what I see, it might be
tc.UserGroup.Users.Any(u=>u.ID.Equals(authenticatedUserId)

OR 
tc.UserGroup.Users.UserId == authenticatedId (if each group has only one user)


BTW: there was no need for -ve. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment AD.Net. BTW, I did not do that.